# PHP Multiarray LOOP WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, function

Hey guys i would like to repeat this statement 13 times by change this statement within a loop or something. `"WHERE spending.SectorID = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13"` how can i successfully do it without typing this code 12 more times. and i would to display the data individually though~ like`where sectorid = 1;` belong to a table with a button to initiate that particular query

```
<?php
$spendingname= array();
$spendingpercent = array();
$spendingid = array();

mysql_select_db($database_conn2, $conn2);
$query_Spending = "SELECT CONCAT(spending.SectorID, spending.ExpenditureID) AS 'SpendingID',
expenditure.ExpenditureName, spending.SpendingPercent, spending.SectorID
FROM spending   
INNER JOIN expenditure ON spending.ExpenditureID = expenditure.ExpenditureID
WHERE spending.SectorID = 1";
$Spending = mysql_query($query_Spending, $conn2) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_Spending = mysql_num_rows($Spending);
while($row_Spending = mysql_fetch_assoc($Spending))
{
$spendingname[] = $row_Spending['ExpenditureName'];
$spendingpercent[] = $row_Spending['SpendingPercent'];
$spendingid[]= $row_Spending['SpendingID'];
}
mysql_free_result($Spending);
?>
```

Comment: but guys how will the array recognise it? do i have to ${'spending'.$i}=array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $spendingname= array();
    $spendingpercent = array();
    $spendingid = array();

    mysql_select_db($database_conn2, $conn2);
    for($x=1;$x<14;$x++)
    {
    $query_Spending = "SELECT CONCAT(spending.SectorID, spending.ExpenditureID) AS 'SpendingID',
    expenditure.ExpenditureName, spending.SpendingPercent, spending.SectorID
    FROM spending   
    INNER JOIN expenditure ON spending.ExpenditureID = expenditure.ExpenditureID
    WHERE spending.SectorID = $x";
    $Spending = mysql_query($query_Spending, $conn2) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_Spending = mysql_num_rows($Spending);
    while($row_Spending = mysql_fetch_assoc($Spending))
    {
    $spendingname[$x] = $row_Spending['ExpenditureName'];
    $spendingpercent[$x] = $row_Spending['SpendingPercent'];
    $spendingid[$x]= $row_Spending['SpendingID'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($Spending);
    }

//To access and print all elements.
for($x=1;$x<count($spendingname);$x++)
{
echo "The value for query $x";
echo $spendingname[$x]."  ".$spendingpercent[$x]."  ".$spendingid[$x]."<br><br><br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: will the array manage to store all 13 values simunateaously?>

Comment: The result of the 13 queries will be stored in the array elements seperately. Run the example, you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the main portion of the script in:

```
for ($n in range(1,13)) {
```

or

```
for ($n=1; $n<=13; $n++) {
```

and replace the constant `1` with `$n`

edit: or depending on how you want to present the data finally you might be able to modify the SQL from:

```
WHERE spending.SectorID = 1
```

to

```
WHERE spending.SectorID >= 1 AND spending.SectorID <= 13
```

or

```
WHERE spending.SectorID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
```

(because of the way that MySQL's optimizer works both should be as efficient)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you **DON'T** want to do is make 13 database queries when a single query will suffice. Query once with the following `WHERE` clause, then iterate over the results:

```
WHERE spending.SectorID <= 13 ";
```

-OR-

```
WHERE spending.SectorID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)";
```

Comment: i would like to display the data individually though~ like where sectorid = 1; belong to a table with a button to initiate that particular query. issit possible? i dont want to display all at once

Comment: Yes, it is. I suggest Reading The Fine Manual Entries on [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a preparedStatement with parameters and then, you could loop the executing of the query as well as the result retrieval.

But I don't understand the reason to do so unless you want do something different with different results. Otherwise, why don't you use a

```
WHERE spending.SectorID BETWEEN 1 AND 13 ORDER BY spending.SectorID
```

?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE spend.SectorID > 0 AND spending.SectorID < 13`

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IN` clause.  Specifically, you can do something like `WHERE spending.SectorID IN ('" . implode("','", range(1,13)) ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop a piece of code a specific number of times, you could use a for loop. Here is a PHP script that can be looped 13 times.

```
$loops = 13;
for ($i = 1; $loops <= $i; $i++) {
    //Your code//
}
```

You should also replace "WHERE spending.SectorID = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13" with "WHERE spending.SectorID = $i", and this increment what your SQL statement is searching for each time the code is looped.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sectorcount = $row_SectorCount['COUNT(*)'];
//number of rows in database
mysql_select_db($database_conn2, $conn2);
for($x=1; $x<=$sectorcount; $x++) 
{
${'spendingname'.$x} = array();
${'spendingpercent'.$x} = array();
${'spendingid'.$x} = array();

$query_Spending = "SELECT CONCAT(spending.SectorID, spending.ExpenditureID) AS 'SpendingID',
expenditure.ExpenditureName, spending.SpendingPercent, spending.SectorID
FROM spending   
INNER JOIN expenditure ON spending.ExpenditureID = expenditure.ExpenditureID
WHERE spending.SectorID = $x";
$Spending = mysql_query($query_Spending, $conn2) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_Spending = mysql_num_rows($Spending);

while($row_Spending = mysql_fetch_assoc($Spending))
{
${'spendingname'.$x}[] = $row_Spending['ExpenditureName'];
${'spendingpercent'.$x}[] = $row_Spending['SpendingPercent'];
${'spendingid'.$x}[]= $row_Spending['SpendingID'];
}
mysql_free_result($Spending);
}                   
?>
```

i managed to solve it but however spendingname is the only one unable to retrieve. spendingname is the only string where else percent and id and all integer. is that why this problem occurs